# How to ensure timer remains on single-shooting, instead of self-timer, on CA, on Canon 7D

Tags: canon, canon-7d, self-timer

I often shoot using AEB (auto exposure bracketing) on a Canon EOS 7D, in Custom 1 (C1) mode, to make a HDR photo.

I turn the camera, off, and next day, I might want to take a quick single exposure shot, and turn the mode back to CA, and find the camera will automatically start a 10 second count down. I hate this.

The last time I was using CA, I had manually set the timer mode to single-shooting, yet now the timer mode has grabbed the setting from when I was in C1.

How do I set the default timer mode for CA on a Canon EOS 7D to single-shooting, and not have the timer mode from C1 remain the default timer mode when I next move to CA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First go first, you didn't read the manual.
I'm a pro, but I do it everytime I get a new camera, of course I don't read everything, just the new parts. Read the manual.

- But let me help you. First assign a custom menu's like this C3 to be
  the most used mode, after that C2, C1.
  [Canon EOS 7D custom functions explained](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/technical/eos_7D_custom_functions_explained.do)
- Why every time you shift from C3 back to CA it goes to timer mode...
  You should change the time mode, to single picture.
  [Shooting Modes](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-change-the-drive-mode-on-a-canon-eos-70d.html)